# How to add images,links in between string.xml

Tags: android, xml, image, scroll, textview

I added scrolling activity(textscoll) to my Project.So I wanted to add huge text to that activity and several images in between that huge text.So I added string file in string.xml and called it in scrolling activity(content_textscoll.xml)...

My string file

```
<string name="string_text_file">This is huge text...</string>
```

My content_textscoll.xml

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/text_margin"
            android:text="@string/string_text_file" />
```

My problem is,
*I want to add several images in between above text.How to resolve that problem....?
I can add images to drawble folder.How to call them?
*How to add html links or other activity links

Comment: follow this https://abhiandroid.com/ui/html

Comment: thank you.hope it will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make web view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="abhiandroid.com.htmlexample.MainActivity">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/simpleWebView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

make assest folder if not exist and create new html file there with any name you want, then put your text and images there like this :

```
<p>in this tag (p tag) put your text </p>
<img>in this tag (img tag) put your images </img>
```

in your activity make something like this :

```
 WebView webView;

public String fileName = "yourAssestFileName.html";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // init webView
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.simpleWebView);
    // displaying content in WebView from html file that stored in assets folder
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + fileName);
}
```